# github3.py etag for conditional requests

Tags: python, etag, github3.py

I'm using [github3.py](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py) passing the `etag` parameter each time I call an iterator, for example:

```
user.iter_starred(etag='97ba89b5c009e5530f108a06606f3e2c')
```

in order to avoid to consume my rate limit and performing a [conditional request](http://developer.github.com/v3/#conditional-requests). But no matter what, when I start the iteration github3 always perform a proper request (and so the real data are fetched) decreasing the rate limit by 1.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

From my own experimentation this seems to work as expected:

```
>>> import github3
>>> u = github3.user('sigmavirus24')
>>> u
<User [sigmavirus24:Ian Cordasco]>
>>> i = u.iter_starred()
>>> i
<GitHubIterator [-1, /users/sigmavirus24/starred]>
>>> next(i)
<Repository [functional-koans/clojure-koans]>
>>> i.etag
'"1aeaaa7a249610c52ba0363009afcab9"'
>>> next(u.iter_starred(etag=i.etag))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "github3/structs.py", line 103, in next
    return self.__next__()
  File "github3/structs.py", line 90, in __next__
    return next(self.__i__)
StopIteration
```

The difference between our examples is that your etag value is `'97ba89b5c009e5530f108a06606f3e2c'`, where as the equivalent to mine is `'"97ba89b5c009e5530f108a06606f3e2c"'`. Since this value is placed in the headers I think it is important that the header be:

```
If-None-Match: "97ba89b5c009e5530f108a06606f3e2c"
```

Instead of:

```
If-None-Match: 97ba89b5c009e5530f108a06606f3e2c
```

Which is what yours will send.

And I just checked and that is what's wrong. The library works as expected. The way you're passing your etag value is wrong. It needs to have double quotes around the value (e.g., `'"97ba89b5c009e5530f108a06606f3e2c"'`) to work properly.

Comment: I don't understand. You say we need to pass the etag formatted similar to this: `'"97ba89b5"'` but that is exactly what is contained in `i.etag`, so why does it throws an error when you pass it as a parameter `u.iter_starred(etag=i.etag)` instead of `u.iter_starred(etag='"97ba89b5"')`? They are supposed to be exactly the same

Comment: BTW none of them work for me, if I pass `i.etag` I get an error similar to the one you've got. If I pass a string similaro ti this `'"97ba89b5"'` I get back the resource with a new etag each time

Comment: The error is the expected behaviour. It means the request completed and nothing was to be returned. Had I gone and starred a new repository it would have returned only that repository.